# Under Printf arithmetic operation precedence

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{
    float a=5.0;
    printf("The Output is %.2f",(7/5)*a+12);
 }
```

I thought the output is 19.00 but the output is 17.00. How this is possible?. Please guide me how the output is 17.00 came....

Comment: `printf` doesn't change the result at all. You could calculate it in any other context and you'd get the same result.

Comment: regarding: `float a=5.0;`  the literal `5.0` is a `double`, but the code is trying to place that double into a float.  Suggest: `float a=5.0f;`  (Note the trailing `f` in the literal)

Comment: integer division drops any fraction.   It seems your expecting the fraction to be kept

Answer (score 10):

`7/5` is 1. That's integer division. Everything after that should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your 7/5 gives an integer result, in this case 1. If you want to get 1.4 you need to change to 7.0/5.0 to get a float result, which will change the result.

Comment: Detail: "change to 7.0/5.0 " will provide a `double` result, not float - yet the approach is sound.